# How to echo a MSSQL datetime field $row into PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, date, strtotime

I'm trying to create a simple table displaying data from June 2019, however i'm having trouble getting the MSSQL datetime row to eacho out properly. Initially it broke my code and was blank, then i tried using the date() strtotime php function, which now just shows 31 01 1970 for all columns which is incorrect.

Here's a example of the input 2016-07-04 00:00:00.000

Below is my code.

```
    <?php
$serverName = "SQL,1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );


$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [all sales data]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
?>

<tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Order Point Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Analysis Category'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Branch Code'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date("d m Y", strtotime($row->date));?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Product Discount Group'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Cost of Sale'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Other Value'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Sales Value'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Analysis Quantity'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Invoice Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Magic Number'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Order Number'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 1'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 2'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 3'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 4'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Product Code'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Salesman 1'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Statement Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Supplier Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Contact']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Order Source'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['User'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Customer Order No'];?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>


            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

below is the vardump

> object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-07-04 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" }

Here's the result of print_r($row);

> Array ( [Order Point Account] =>  [Analysis Category] => AD [Branch Code] => 100 [Transaction Date] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-07-04 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/London ) [Product Discount Group] =>  [End Product Cost of Sale] => 165.19999694824 [End Product Other Value] => 165.2 [End Product Sales Value] => 369.60000610352 [End Product Analysis Quantity] => 1 [Invoice Account] =>  [Magic Number] => 800713 [Sales Order Line Number] => [Order Number] => 319651 [PAC Level 1] => d [PAC Level 2] => dLB [PAC Level 3] => dLB01 [PAC Level 4] => dLB0106 [Product Code] =>  [Salesman 1] => 9500 [Statement Account] =>  [Supplier Account] =>  [Contact] => fax [Order Source] => FAX [User] =>  [Customer Order No] =>  )

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong to get this data to display correctly?

Many thanks!

Comment: `$row,['Transaction Date']` ?? is it typo? should be $row['Transaction Date']

Comment: Changed it to $row['Transaction Date'] still no luck.

Comment: you are getting response in object form why are u trying to print like an array???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 issues in your code:

**Issue 1:**

You have typo here `$row,[Transaction Date]`.

**Issue 2:**

Your column name is `date` not `Transaction Date`

**Issue 3:**

Your response in object form not in array format.

**Issue 4:**

You are using `t` in date format, which return `Number of days in the given month`

```
<td><?php echo date("t m Y", strtotime($row,['Transaction Date']));?></td>
```

**Should be:**

```
<td><?php echo date("d m Y", strtotime($row->date));?></td>
```

[PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I see that makes sense thanks, i'm very new to this. I've amended the code to <td><?php echo date("t m Y", strtotime($row->date));?></td>. However it still echo's the same result as before 31 01 1970 for all rows.

Comment: @Chris: alright, share the result of    `print_r($row);`

Comment: @Chris: now i found 4th issue, check updated answer

Comment: @Chris: share your code also, where you are using this,

Comment: `<td><?php echo date("t m Y", strtotime($row['Transaction Date']->date));?></td>` use this @Chris

Comment: Ok so <td><?php echo date("d m Y", strtotime($row['Transaction Date']->date));?></td> works perfectly except for some very strange reason doesn't work whenever i take away the line before <?php var_dump( $row['Transaction Date']);?>. When this line is deleted, all the dates break again???

Comment: @Chris: maybe this something else... so your actuall issue has been solved, you can create another question for new issue, and close this question, by mark as accepted from left hand side tick..